# Windows Phone 10 resolution in Edge

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

I have problem with Windows Phone 10. I have Microsoft Lumia 550 (1280 x 720) and web site which I created is width exactly 720px, but in my browser (Edge) I can see only half of page width. Does anyone have idea what can be reason of this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edge favors responsive design, and uses effective pixels to determine how to rescale things. (Very quick explanation of effective pixels: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/Scaling-and-effective-pixels-in-UWP-apps) If your web site is hard coded to be exactly 720 pixels on desktop, it might be trying to rescale it for this window.

Be sure you are using a type of detection to see what the width of the screen is, then you can display the appropriate site. For example, you can do this in CSS with media query -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg124120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Using the F12 tools on Desktop Edge will help you to test the web site and see what it's doing when it puts together your layout. You can emulate the phone on Desktop with this for testing.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So is there any way to set display of my windows mobile to see the real width (720px). I tried to set viewport in my webpage as: 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=720, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
But the efect is same. On other phones it looks correct. So Is not this problem only on windows phone?

Comment: Yes, the problem is probably only on Windows phone, so you should detect if you are on a certain screen size and then you can set it to display correctly.

Comment: Is it a Windows Phone problem, or a Microsoft Edge problem?